# When is damage "permanent" in Accel World?

Tags: accel-world

Within the accelerated world, when someone gets damaged or injured (even severely), they fully recover after leaving and re-entering the accelerated realm. (If you are killed you also come back normally.)

For example:

- Taku cuts off Haruyuki's arm. (ep 5)
- Niko's left arm is ripped off when Yellow Radio's minions tear apart her fortress. (ep 11)

[image: Taku cuts off Haruyuki's arm. (ep 5, 4:05)][image: Niko's left arm is detached when Yellow Radio's minions tear apart per fortress. (ep 11, 15:45)]

Both of these injuries (a loss of an entire limb) are serious injuries that can't be recovered in battle.* However, when they leave and re-enter the accelerated world, they are fully recovered.

<sup>*Barring Chiyuri's time-reversal ability.</sup>

---

But there are at least two instances of when damage is not reversed upon re-entering the accelerated world:

- Kuroyukihime amputates Fuuko's legs - hence the wheelchair. (described in ep 16)
- Noumi steals Haruyuki's wings. (ep 15)

[image: Fuuko is in a wheelchair because she no longer has legs.][image: Noumi steals Haruyuki's wings.]

So what determines whether damage is healed?

Furthermore, how does Chiyuri's time-reversal ability play into this?

Answer (score 5):

It seems not to be some kind of "rule", but aspect of specific stronger abilities/avatars:

- it was explicitly said that Black Lotus avatar inflicts permanent damage with her blades
- "steal" ability wouldn't be much of a steal without permanent aspect to it

I don't think it was explored (in anime at least) if there are ways to purposely achieve it (from leveling up would be logical) or as other aspects of avatars some people just happen to have it.

Comment: Could you cite where it is explicitly said that Kuroyukihime inflict permanent damage with per blades? Furthermore, she slices up quite a few avatars in the show. Certainly not *all* of those can be permanent no? That would imply that any kill she gets is permanent.

Comment: I don't have anime on hand to try look up precise quotes. Looking online I see that commonly used phrasing is along the lines of "parts cut off from avatar by her stay off" so likely it doesn't apply to kills. At the very least it was strongly implied that Sky Raker asked her to cut of her avatar's legs _because_ it was only [available] way to do it permanently.

Answer (score 2):

Dusk Taker (Nuomi) ability Demonic Commander can't be considered a ability that deals some kind of "permanent damage" but more like "ability transfer" or "ability taker", for that reason Demonic Commander doesn't deal any damage, and while my memory about the Anime is hazy, I'm pretty sure that the HP bar of Silver Crow (Haruyuki) didn't decreased and that left Haruyuki puzzled at first when Nuomi used such ability. It couldn't be classified as damage hence it's not healed, but restored with the Lime Bell (Chiyuri) ability Citron Call that reverses the status of the avatar/object.

About Sky Rakker (Fuuko) legs is not until latter in the history that this is explained, so this is considered spoiler from the Light Novel (unless the anime decides not to follow the history, this is what happens):

> Black Lotus (Kuroyukihime) didn't used a normal ability but the Incarnated System to cut Sky Rakker legs. This produces a overwriting of Fuuko avatar that whenever she appears in Territory Battles or the Unlimited Field, her legs are not present. This becomes more evident when they try to use Citron Call to restore Sky Rakker legs but it doesn't works since the overwriting of the Incarnated System is stronger than any ability.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Haruyuki's wings act almost like an item, similar to the Gale Thruster, but untradeable. Noumi's special move allowed him to transfer this item to himself. It is noted in the show that Fuuko's legs are now artificial in the real world, implying that Kuroyukihime physically amputated them in the real world.